# Repeated Game Center Welcome Banners

Tags: ios5, game-center

How do you prevent the Game Center "Welcome Back" message from displaying every time your app wakes up from sleep?  Some apps (like Scramble CE, Jetpack Joyride, and Bubblin) handle it correctly (just one welcome message on launch), while others (like Backgammon NJ) don't (welcome message every time the device wakes up).

The block code that's running is no longer in my control (sent to authenticateWithCompletionHandler), and the welcome message appears even if the block is empty anyway.

This behavior started happening with iOS 5.0 (was fine in 4.x), and happens in both the Simulator and real devices, in the Sandbox and not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm from BivisSoft. We've developed Bubblin.

We have a Singleton that controls GameCenter.

Here is our code... 
It's based on tutorial by Jacob Gundersen - http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1.

You can try it!

```
    #pragma mark Singleton

    static BSGameCenterManager *sharedHelper = nil;
    + (BSGameCenterManager *) sharedInstance {
        if (!sharedHelper) {
            sharedHelper = [[BSGameCenterManager alloc] init];
        }
        return sharedHelper;
    }

    #pragma mark Initializers

    - (id)init {
        if ((self = [super init])) {
            gameCenterAvailable = [self isGameCenterAvailable];
            if (gameCenterAvailable) {
                self.localPlayerId = @"";
                NSNotificationCenter *nc = 
                [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
                [nc addObserver:self 
                       selector:@selector(authenticationChanged) 
                           name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName 
                         object:nil];
            }
        }
        return self;
    }

    // Check if GameCenter is Avaiable 
    - (BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable {
        // check for presence of GKLocalPlayer API
        Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

        // check if the device is running iOS 4.1 or later
        NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
        NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer     
                                               options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

        return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
    }

    #pragma mark Authentication

    - (void)authenticationChanged {    

        if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && 
            !self.userAuthenticated) {
            NSLog(@"GameCenter authentication changed: player authenticated.");
            self.userAuthenticated = TRUE;           
            self.localPlayerId = [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] playerID];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"gameCenterPlayerAuthenticated" object: nil userInfo: nil];    
            [self checkNotSentScores];
        } else if (![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && 
                   self.userAuthenticated) {
            NSLog(@"GameCenter authentication changed: player not authenticated");
            self.userAuthenticated = FALSE;
            self.localPlayerId = @"";
        }
    }

    - (void)authenticateLocalUser { 

        if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

        NSLog(@"GameCenter authenticating local user...");
        if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {     
            [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] 
             authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];        
        } else {
            NSLog(@"GameCenter already authenticated!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  The only thing different I see offhand is the singleton part, but I'll definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In the Game Kit programming guide I found this bit of documentation:

> All games that support Game Center must authenticate the local player
>   before using any of Game Center’s features. Your game should
>   authenticate the player as early as possible after launching. Ideally,
>   authentication should happen as soon as your game can present a user
>   interface to the player. When your game authenticates a player, Game
>   Kit first checks to see whether there is already an authenticated
>   player on the device. **If there is an authenticated player, Game Kit
>   briefly displays a welcome banner to the player.**

It doesn't seem as if you can change this behavior with the public API's.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that.  I just know that apps in the App Store are getting around this, and I'd like to, too!

Comment: Well you would need to use some undocumented API call to make it happen or somehow bypass the GK authentication check when its not needed.